# Site for Biblio software usage questions

Tags: discussion, scope

Is this the SE site for asking usage questions about [Biblio software](http://silvermountainsoftware.com/bibloi.html)?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  This site discusses the interpretation of specific Bible passages.  To ask about the use of Bible software, you might ask the software providers and users.

Answer (score 1):

Questions about dedicated Bible software may be on-topic, with the [tools-of-biblical-studies](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools-of-biblical-studies) tag. Questions can still be closed for being too broad, opinion based, etc. So a question asking how to perform a specific query in one of the Bible apps is probably okay, but it should be quite specific, and not ask for how to use the app in general.

I'm not sure I've seen anyone here who uses Biblio though, so you may be waiting a while for an answer. Accordance and Logos are more common.